# How to pick top 5 values from a hash?

Tags: ruby, arrays, sorting, hash, hashmap

I have a hash of ids and their scores, it's something like this:

```
@objects = {1=>57, 4=>12, 3=>9, 5=>3, 55=>47, 32=>39, 17=>27, 29=>97, 39=>58}
```

How can I pick the top five and drop the rest ?

I'm doing this:

```
@orderedObject = @objects.sort_by {|k,v| v}.reverse
=>[[29, 97], [39, 58], [1, 57], [55, 47], [32, 39], [17, 27], [4, 12], [3, 9], [5, 3]]
```

Then I do this:
only Keys of the `@orderedObjects`:

```
@keys = @orderedObject.map { |key, value| key }
```

which gives me:

```
=>[29, 39, 1, 55, 32, 17, 4, 3, 5]
```

**ALL** I need is `[29, 39, 1, 55, 32]` the first 5 indexes. **But** I'm stuck I don't know how to do this.

Comment: Ob, imo, you really should wait a little longer before selecting an answer, as quick-draw checkmarks may discourage other, sometimes better solutions.  Even if later solutions are not better, a greater diversity of answers helps us all hone our Ruby skills.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do

```
@objects = {1=>57, 4=>12, 3=>9, 5=>3, 55=>47, 32=>39, 17=>27, 29=>97, 39=>58}
@objects.sort_by { |_, v| -v }[0..4].map(&:first)
# => [29, 39, 1, 55, 32]
@objects.sort_by { |_, v| -v }.first(5).map(&:first)
# => [29, 39, 1, 55, 32]
```

Comment: Owww My God! THANK You so much! Quickest answer ever I've gotten on StackOverflow!

Comment: Observer, you must understand the Arup has compiled PostgreSQL in his brain.  He just feeds in the questions and out pop the answers.

Answer (score 1):

A variant of Prof. Arup's answer:

```
objects = {1=>57, 4=>12, 3=>9, 5=>3, 55=>47, 32=>39, 17=>27, 29=>97, 39=>58}

objects.sort_by { |k,v| -v }.first(5).to_h.keys #=> [29, 39, 1, 55, 32]
```

**Now suppose** `3=>9` were instead `3=>39` and you wanted the keys corresponding to the top 5 values (which, in this case, would be 6 keys, as `39` is the fifth largest value, `3=>39` and `32=>39`), you could first compute:

```
threshold = objects.values.sort.last(5).min #=> 39
```

If you wanted the keys to be ordered by the order of values `threshold` or larger,

```
objects.select { |_,v| v >= threshold }.sort_by { |_,v| -v }.map(&:first)
  #=> [29, 39, 1, 55, 3, 32]
```

If you don't care about the order,

```
objects.select { |_,v| v >= threshold }.keys #=> [1, 3, 55, 32, 29, 39]
```

Answer (score 1):

May i suggest this more verbose requires ruby > 1.9

```
Hash[@objects.sort_by{|k,v| -v}.first(5)].keys
```